# Этот вопрос немного непра-, по-моему, -вильный

Tags: орфография

Можете сказать, как нужно правильно писать слово, которое ты разъединяешь, вставляя в середину какое-то другое слово или вообще фразу? Я полагаю, что нужно просто-напросто, как в моём примере, использовать два дефиса. Правильно?

Этот вопрос немного **непра-, по-моему, -вильный.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно! Другие варианты будут еще неПРАВИльнее...

Ведь и правила пока еще нет, только ваш вариант...

```
                    (Справочная служба)
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, нужно использовать два дефиса с обоих сторон. Вы всё правильно написали!

Comment: Сторона — слово жен. рода. И о второй фразе вопрос: какой смысл у восклицательного знака?